# using \frontmatter kills my {geometry} definitions

Tags: margins, geometry, front-matter

I use a the jura package to write some home work in Law (to be honest, I'm just helping my girlfriend ...). Anyways, I the header of the document I have:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{jura}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy paragraphs.

\usepackage[
    top=3cm, 
    bottom=3cm, 
    left=7cm, 
    right=.2cm, 
    width=500pt,
    marginparwidth=0pt]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\frontmatter
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

If I include the `\frontmatter` command, the definitions by geometry package are overridden (note that I need to use the `jura` document class).

How can I reverse this? Can I have an in-document (e.g. no it preamble) command to change the right margin?

Comment: I see that the geometry package has such options, but I'm using Debian Squeeze, and I rather not start messing around with installing new latex packages ...

Comment: I took the liberty of removing any unnecessary stuff from your example in the hope that it makes the question clearer and also added that you need to use the `jura` class.

Comment: (Manually installing TeX Live surprisingly easy and will give you all the updated packages and less bugs than the Debian/Ubuntu `texlive` packages.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, my lame solution so far is to use the package "chagnepage"

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{jura}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Silbentrennung
\usepackage{ngerman}%Deutsche Sonderzeichen und Silbentrennung (neue Rechtschreibung)

\usepackage{times}
% \usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=7cm, right=.2cm,width = 500pt,marginparwidth=0pt]{geometry}
...
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\lipsum[1]
\mainmatter
\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-1.3cm}
\lipsum
...
end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{jura}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Silbentrennung
\usepackage{ngerman}%Deutsche Sonderzeichen und Silbentrennung (neue Rechtschreibung)

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[%
                        a4paper,
                        twoside,
                        vmargin=30mm,
                        left=70mm,
                        right=2mm,
                        showframe=true%
                     ]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}%dummy paragraphs.

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note: I added twoside option. You can remove if you don't want two side document.

Comment: Is it mandatory to use jura document class? It is very old document class. :-)

Comment: @export, it is indeed a very old class, but i can't find a better replacement ... German law typesetting is pretty complicated. Also your solution does not work for me. Maybe it is bug in Debian ? Which OS you use ? which version of the Geometry packages do you use ?

Comment: your code gives a different layout than the code in the question, or am I missing something?

Comment: I think the original geometry option of @Oz123 is over populated. It means that the width=500pt will never be taken into account by geometry.sty.